# Loss of Unicode data - due to collation change?

Tags: sql, sql-server, collate

I had a table with a collation of `Thai_CI_AS` which did not store special characters like `à` properly.
When storing `à` it gets rendered as a question mark: `?`

I have solved the problem by changing the collation of that table to default which is latin*.

New data (special characters) are now being stored correctly.

But the old data still displays `???`.

How do I refresh or whatever it's called to make the old data display properly?

----- edit -------

Is there an sql query that allows one to change all `?` to something else like `à`?

Example

```
 ?sometext?
 ??sometext??
 ?????
 sometext??
```

and turn all to

```
 àsometextà
 àsometextà
 ààààà
 sometextàà
```

Thank you,
The following columns are the one that contains those kinds of data's,

```
 id_name1, id_name2, id_name3.
```

Please help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to say, but your old data is gone. I don't think this is because of the collation; it probably happened because you did this:

```
INSERT dbo.table(column) SELECT 'à';
```

Instead of properly prefixing Unicode data with the N character:

```
INSERT dbo.table(column) SELECT N'à';
---- this is important ---------^
```

But again, there is no getting that old data back... you even said yourself that when you stored the data under Thai collation, it showed `?` - this means the data was never stored properly in the first place (most likely because of the missing `N`).

Comment: I see. Thanks though. Any advice, I want to just change all `?` to something else? Thank you.

Comment: Like instead of question marks make all of the question marks on all columns to an à? Example some column contains `?sometext?` some has `????` I want to change this to `àsometextà` and `àààà`.

Comment: @user1543644 do you think every question mark in your table was supposed to be a `à`, and no other "special characters" could have been used by anybody? What about real question marks at the end of a sentence?

Comment: There is no problem for that :) I know its all `à`. How can this be done?

Comment: does changing varchar to NVARCHAR do anything?

Comment: If you want to replace text, you use the [`REPLACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862(v=sql.100).aspx) function. Mind-boggling, I know. Changing the data type after the fact is not going to resurrect your old data. But are you saying the column is varchar, not nvarchar? Is `à` really the character you're after? If so, `UPDATE dbo.table SET column = REPLACE(column, 'à', '?');`

Comment: @user1543644 - `NVARCHAR` will also support those chars which are not in your keyboard.

Comment: I believe it should be...  `UPDATE dbo.table SET column = REPLACE(column, '?', 'à');`   thanks alot :)

Comment: @user1543644 yep, got it backwards, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If this question relates to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619569/), then the answer is Yes.

A VARCHAR column only holds single-byte characters. In your case, you should change the VARCHAR columns to NVARCHAR, and then change the columns' collation.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer but everything is still ???? after doing what you said. But I guess I'll just manually change all the `?` after all :)